# What's the remainder if $99{,}999^{99}$ is divided by $999{,}999$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What's the remainder if $99{,}999^{99}$ is divided by $999{,}999$?

Is there any formula or trick method to achieve this?
Also kindly ignore the improper use of tag as i don't know which tag to choose

Comment: Hint: relabel $999999$ as $x$. What's the remainder after division?

Comment: Computer says 123579, but I don't see *elegant* trick besides laboriously doing square-and-multiply

Comment: @JohnDouma: I don't get it.

Comment: @Hagen Your hardware is consistent with my wetware - see my answer.

Comment: @TonyK I misread the question. I thought both numbers consisted of six $9$s.

Comment: @JohnDouma, I miscounted the 9's at first too. I've inserted commas for clarity.

Comment: Okay,  Chinese remainder theory comes out that $N=99,999^{99} \equiv 0 \mod 27\equiv 1\mod 7*37\equiv 5\mod 11\equiv 8\mod 13$.  And ... well, that can be solve by euclid's algorithm but I didn't want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

$\!\bmod 999999\!:\,\ 10\cdot99999\equiv -9\ $ so $\ 99999 \equiv -9/10$

Thus $\,99999^{\large99}\equiv -9^{\large 99}/10^{\large 99}\equiv -9^{\large 99}/10^{\large 3}\equiv -10^{\large 3}\cdot 9^{\large 99}\ $ via $\ 10^{\large 
 6}\equiv 1$

$n := 999999/27 =  7\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 37.\,$ mod each $p,\,$ $9\,$ has order $\,3,5,3,9\,$ so $\,9^{\large \color{#c00}{45}}\equiv 1\pmod{\!n}$

so $\ 9^{\large 99}\!\bmod 999999 = 27(3\cdot 9^{\large \color{#c00}{97}}\!\bmod n) = 27(3\cdot 9^{\large 7}\!\bmod n) \equiv 9^{\large 9}\!\pmod{\!999999}$

Hence we conclude $\ 99999^{\large 99}\equiv -10^{\large 3}\cdot 9^{\large 99}\equiv {-}10^{\large 3}\cdot 9^{\large 9}\equiv 123579\,\pmod{\!999999}$

Comment: Due to $999999$ isn't a prime number you should say that $10$ has an inverse because it's coprime with $999999$.

Comment: Then you can't arbitrarly pass from mod $999999$ to mod $n$.

Comment: He's using the Chinese remainder theorem there. It's clear that $99999^{99} \equiv 0 \bmod 27$.

Comment: @PDeDonato That's obvious: $\bmod 10^6-1\!:\,\ 10\cdot 10^5\equiv 1\ $ so $10^{-1}\equiv 10^5\ \ $

Comment: I know it, but the answer isn't so clear.

Comment: @Qiaochu Actually I use the [mod Distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242)  $\,ab\bmod ac = a(b\bmod c),\,$ which can be viewed as an operational form of CRT (they are equivalent)

Comment: @PDeDonato Please see the prior comment.

Comment: Thank you very much @BillDubuque

Answer (score 2):

We work in the ring $R=\Bbb Z/N$, with operation modulo $N=999999=10^6-1$. 
(Equalities below address computations in $R$.)
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
99999^{99}
&=(99999-999999)^{99} =(-900000)^{99}=-9^{99}\cdot (10^5)^{99}\\
&=-3^{198}\cdot 10^{495}=-3^{198}\cdot {\underbrace{(10^6)}_{=1}}^{82}\cdot 10^3=-3^{198}\cdot 1000\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now the order of (the unit) $3$ in the ring

$\Bbb Z/37037
=\Bbb Z/(7\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 37)
\cong
(\Bbb Z/7)\times
(\Bbb Z/11)\times
(\Bbb Z/13)\times
(\Bbb Z/37)
$

is $90$, but we need only the simpler information that $3^{180}$ is one modulo $37037$. This is so because $180$ is a multiple of $(7-1)$, $(11-1)$, $(13-1)$, and $(37-1)$. So instead of $3^{198}$ we write the smaller power $3^{18}=387420489$.

We finally search for a number which is $0$ modulo $27$, and also $-387420489000$ modulo $37037$, which is $12468$. After rearrangements modulo $3,9,27$ we get the result
$$123579\ .$$

---

Note: A computer algebra system like [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) delivers immediately

```
sage: Zmod(999999)(99999)^99
123579
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as my answer, except I used the mod distributive law form of CRT (which makes it simpler).

Comment: I committed it now after typing in the train... Yes, same computation.

Comment: Thank you very much, it took some time but i eventually understood